# Biblatex and mla-paper making weird headings

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, sectioning, mla-style

I'm trying to use mla-paper and biblatex with MLA style in the same document so I can have a managed bibliography but with the whole document in MLA. I seem to have it working almost properly, but it produces a bibliography heading that is larger than the title of the document. I'm getting this error:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
Make it at least 14.49998pt.
We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.`
```

But I'm not really sure what to do with it. It seems like it's making the bibliography heading bigger than I'd like it to. How can I fix this?

Either a direct solution or more general tips on better ways to use MLA with BibTex and LaTeX would be great. Thanks.

**Update**

Here's a full minimal example of what I'm doing and a link to an image of what I'm getting.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{mla}
\bibliography{../Bibliography/Bibliography}
\begin{document}
\begin{mla}{Stephen}{Searles}{Schultz}{Queering American History}{\today}{Week 7}
Test sentence. \autocite{Somerville:2005fk}. 
\begin{center}
\printbibliography
\end{center}
\end{mla}
\end{document}
```

Along with a standard BibTex file with that cite key, of course. It's citing properly as you'll see, so that's not the problem. [image: Here is an image of what it outputs.]

Comment: We will want a full minimal example of your code

Comment: The warning message has nothing to do with the size of the bibliography heading. `fancyhdr` merely tells you that it can't put the header text (“Searles 1” in your example) in the 12pt space you reserve for it with `\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}`. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2394/what-is-causing-different-spacing-between-a-header-and-content-on-one-page-only

Comment: Oh whoops. That line should have been taken out (reflected above now). I added that trying to fix that message. It, clearly, did not work, but I forgot to remove it.

Comment: When I follow the advice of that answer and `fancyhdr`, the message doesn't go away. I guess I have two problems then...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main problem you have is the size of your "Works Cited" part.  This is because the label is being generated by the `biblatex-mla` and not by the `mla` package.  To fix this you  could enclose the bibliography in the `mla`'s `workscited` environment and redefine `biblatex`'s `bibheading` to nothing.  Alternatively, you can simply redefine `bibheading` to what the `mla` package defines it as, which is simpler:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{mla}
\defbibheading{bibliography}{\newpage\centering Works Cited}
\bibliography{../Bibliography/Bibliography}
\begin{document}
\begin{mla}{Stephen}{Searles}{Schultz}{Queering American History}{\today}{Week 7}
Test sentence. \autocite{Somerville:2005fk}. 
\begin{center}
\printbibliography
\end{center}
\end{mla}
\end{document}
```

The `mla` package leaves a lot to be desired.  It should use the `setspace` package for linespacing, instead of simply using `\linespread`. It also has a manual hack `\tab` for indenting paragraphs after sections, among other things.  But if it is more or less working for you, that's ok.  I don't know of an equivalent package for this kind of use.

Answer (score 4):

I know this may seem like a late reply, but I think it would help people who are still seeking a good answer to this question. I found this package online called MLA13 that does everything for you. I used it in quite a few of my papers already. The thing that's good about it is that it uses your .bib files and formats everything according to MLA standards.

The website for this is:

Documentation: http://jackson13.info/mla13/Documentation.pdf

Github: https://github.com/jackson13info/mla13

This package formats the header according to mla style by centering it and making it of font size 12.