# Authoring an MLA-conforming document in LaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, templates, mla-style

I am trying to write a paper in proper MLA (Modern Language Association) [format](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/01/), but I am having trouble understanding how it all goes together. Is there an example document or template for MLA (with citations, including parenthetical) for (La)TeX? I find incomplete examples all over the place and I just can't seem to put it together correctly.

Comment: Do you mean MLA style citations? If so, use the `biblatex-mla` package. If you mean a paper for a class, there isn't a very good format around, but the following might be sufficient: [biblatex and mla-paper making weird headings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11172/2693).

Comment: When had to write a paper in MLA style, I found all the templates on the web insufficient, so I hacked together the format on my own. I didn't use any automatic bibliography packages/tools, though.

Comment: If Alan's answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left, thereby marking the question as "solved", and awarding some points to both Alan and yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need MLA-style citations for an article or paper, use the [`biblatex-mla`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-mla) package.

If you are looking for a specific document class for a term paper for a class that needs to be in MLA style there isn't a very good format around, although there is the [`mla-paper`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mla-paper) package.  To use the `mla-paper` package with `biblatex-mla` see this question here:  [biblatex and mla-paper making weird headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11172/2693).

Since the kinds of formatting required for a term paper may be quite relaxed, it might be better to just format your paper yourself using standard packages such as `titlesec` plus the `setspace` package for double spacing (which is often required by professors.) than to use `mla-package`.

Answer (score 2):

For most academic work, I find Ryan Aycock's [MLA package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mla-paper/) sufficient. I've had problems citing URLs, movies and DVDs with biblatex-mla.

```
\usepackage{mla}
```

Good luck.