# Author's name article dropped with \citename

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am having a problem with `\citename` dropping a name article, e.g. printing "Foerster" instead of "Von Foerster" in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\DeclareNameFormat{idem}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\newcommand*{\person}[2]{%
  \citename{#1}[#2]{author}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{foerster1979cybernetics,
    AUTHOR = "von Foerster, Heinz"
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\person{foerster1979cybernetics}{idem} described this as a shift from...
\end{document}
```

How can I change this to properly print "Von Foerster described this as a shift from..." (it should automatically capitalise the 'v' as the macro appears at the beginning of a sentence).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load `biblatex` with the option setting `useprefix=true` (or simply `useprefix`). This will (1) print any last name prefix in citations and (2) include prefixes in sorting. Marco shows how you can do (1) but not (2) in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30277/4483).

To capitalize the prefix, you can use a variant of `\person`:

```
\newcommand*{\Person}[2]{\bibsentence\citename{#1}[#2]{author}}
```