# biblatex-mla -- Wrong hanging indent size

Tags: biblatex, mla-style

I'm using biblatex-mla (based off the template in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11189/81508)).

It works perfectly except, the hanging indent in biblatex-mla is 1/2 the length it should be (which is 0.5in) according to the MLA spec.

How do I fix this?

MWE: `test.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}
\usepackage{ifpdf}% required by mla.sty
\usepackage{mla}
\defbibheading{bibliography}{\newpage\centering Works Cited}
\bibliography{main.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mla}{Stephen}{Searles}{Schultz}{Queering American History}{\today}{Week 7}

Test sentence. \autocite{Somerville:2005fk}.

\printbibliography
\end{mla}
\end{document}
```

`main.bib`

```
@Online{Somerville:2005fk,
  Title                    = {Dr. James Maas, Professor and Bestselling Author, and Consultant Rebecca Robbins on Sleep for Success},
  Author                   = {Ken Dawson and Sheryl Dawson},

  Year                     = {2010},
  Urldate                  = {2015-08-11},

  Maintitle                = {From Career Treadmill to Fast Track},
  Publisher                = {n.p.}
```

}

Comment: What should be the hangindent?

Comment: `mla` is not a very well coded package, IMNSHO. Certainly, it is using stuff which is long obsolete, such as the `times` package which shouldn't be used any longer.

Comment: @cfr I haven't found a working alternative (`mla13` has extra space after the title). What should be used in place of `times` package?

Comment: I use `\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}` but there are alternatives to this, if preferred. But I think for standard 'We demand Times!' this is probably pretty safe. To be honest, `mla.sty` doesn't do anything you couldn't do better and more easily yourself in a few lines of preamble. At least half of it could be replaced by `geometry` and much of the rest by use of the `setspace` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've found; simply add this to your preamble:

```
\bibhang=40pt
```

Is thtat what you want?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `0.5in`?My professor is going to go at this with a ruler in hand and `40pt` isn't `0.5in`.

Comment: Because I read it in `mla.sty`. I didn't invent it. It's up to you to change this value to whatever you please. You're right 0.5in $\approx$ 36pt. (depending on the type of point.

Answer (score 2):

You could `\setlength{\bibhang}{2\bibhang}` if you're absolutely positive it's only half the desired value (or set it to the value itself `\setlength{\bibhang}{<value>}`).

About your MWE: `mla` requires loading the `ifpdf` package and you should prefer `addbibresource` instead of `bibliography` with biblatex.

Heres your MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Online{Somerville:2005fk,
  Title                    = {Dr. James Maas, Professor and Bestselling Author, and Consultant Rebecca Robbins on Sleep for Success},
  Author                   = {Ken Dawson and Sheryl Dawson},
  Year                     = {2010},
  Urldate                  = {2015-08-11},
  Maintitle                = {From Career Treadmill to Fast Track},
  Publisher                = {n.p.}  
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\defbibheading{bibliography}{\newpage\centering Works Cited}
\usepackage{ifpdf}% required by mla.sty
\usepackage{mla}
\setlength{\bibhang}{2\bibhang}

\begin{document}
\begin{mla}{Stephen}{Searles}{Schultz}{Queering American History}{\today}{Week 7}

Test sentence. \autocite{Somerville:2005fk}.

\printbibliography
\end{mla}
\end{document}
```

And (an adapted) sample output:

> [image: mwe sample]